# how to create a thread for the class which is inherited by QWidget?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, qt4

I want to create a thread for a class which is Inherited by QWidget. Actually, I tried with multiple inheritance with QThread and it fails and I want to run particular member function using thread. How can I achieve this? Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: How does it "fail"? Build error? Run time error?

Comment: Multiple inheritance from two QObjects is a no-no. It is an example  of the common ancestor/diamond problem in multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ joachim : Build Error : It throws following error : error C2385: ambiguous access of 'connect'
1>        could be the 'connect' in base 'QObject'
1>        or could be the 'connect' in base 'QObject'

Answer (score 2):

You could use a wrapper class that implements the thread and calls your widget's method:

```
class MyWidget : public QWidget
{ 
    [...]

    void threadMethod();
};

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    [...]

    MyThread( MyWidget* widget )
      : mWidget(widget)
    {
    }

    void run()
    {
       mWidget->threadMethod();
    }

    MyWidget* mWidget;
};
```

However, you should not call any QWidget methods in "threadMethod", since the GUI and and thus the widgets belong to the "main" thread, and the QWidget methods are not thread-safe!

It would probably better to keep your widget and thread code completely separate.

Comment: Thanks hmn . But what is that "mWidget" stands here ?

Comment: "mWidget" is the member variable that holds the reference to the widget. I have added it in the code example for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to use nested class in which you will pass a pointer to your normal widget class and all all methods you need from nested run method.

Answer (score 0):

Qt classes which belong to the GUI module are not reentrant. They MUST be run from the main thread.